# How to connect to WiFi on iPhone programmatically? (LEAP Protocol)

Tags: iphone, wifi

I need to do an app for my school to connect to the Wi-Fi Network. They use a LEAP protocol and I just need to send a NSURLRequest to a PHP file.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone [supports LEAP](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_WPA2.pdf) natively - your app doesn't have to do anything special to support it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the job of your app to connect to the wireless! If the iPhone supports LEAP authentication, you should just connect. If not, you're out of luck. You can't* alter the wifi settings of the iPhone from inside an application.

As for a NSURLRequest, you'd just use a normal NSURLConnection and let the iPhone do all the LEAP stuff behind the scenes for you.

*As far as I know, maybe jailbroken phones can do more.

Comment: Provided username and password (possibly not already in the keychain), do you know if it would be possible to make the phone attempt to connect to a known secured WiFi?

Comment: Yes - it will do that automatically when you attempt to do anything networky. AFAIK you can't explicitly trigger it though